# Native javascript drag on table rows

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've tried to implement some kind of draggable table rows. I know jquery ui has a drag- and droppable widget (I have tried it and it works really good, so far), but I've wanted to implement it with the native drag and drop browser events.

Everything works as expected on the ul list, but while dragging, the feedback element on the tr looses the background color.

If you try the following snippet,
http://jsfiddle.net/NuLLn/5/
you will see that behaviour. (In Firefox, Safari doesn't play nicely with the table anyway)

Is this the normal behaviour for drag elements, or am I'm missing something here?

Tank you!

Comment: I know this might not be what you want to hear, but don't try to reinvent the wheel.  The drag and drop that comes with jqueryui is useful because it supports most modern browsers, and it 'just works'.  Also, under the surface it does indeed use the native drag and drop events :)

Comment: Thanks soniic, couldn't find information that it uses the native events. If so, that's perfect for my needs.

Comment: @soniiic Agreed. With Chrome at equal or greater market share with Firefox, you need to support it, and it sounds like the OP hasn't even started down that path yet.

Comment: @GregL I have allready implemeted it with jquery ui... but was thinking, it might be fun to play around with a handcrafted simpler solution. But think I use with jquery ui... no headaches anymore :-)

Comment: Yeah. If it was the size of the jQuery UI library that worried you, don't forget you can customise which parts of the whole library you want if necessary, so you could just get the "core" and "draggable" parts if you liked.