# HTML5 Native Drag instead of jQuery Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, drag

Is it possible to use the HTML5 drag feature as a replacement to jQuery Draggable?

The only examples I have seen of the HTML5 version is transporting data around the DOM.
Links to examples will suffice.

I did read the comments of this question: [Native javascript drag on table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428177/native-javascript-drag-on-table-rows), and although I may be trying to reinvent the wheel a bit here, my reasoning behind it is that this only needs to support browsers that have this feature.  Additionally I would like to take advantage of the native performance over jQuery in this interaction.

Comment: Yes HTML5 drag and drop is completely doable with HTML5 and Javascript, but there are some limitations to using it compared to the jQuery version, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Like drag and drop photo's or something?

Comment: @MitchellLayzell Hi, sorry for late reply on this comment. Ideally I need to replicate the functionality of jQuery using HTML5.  If the functionality can be completely duplicated I imagine jQuery will eventually be updated to take advantage of this.  Unfortunately I can't wait for them to do that.